# Restrict access to classes in Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

I want to restrict certain users from accessing a class called `Item` in my parse database. I created a role called `blockedUsers` and added some users to it.

Now I am confused as to how I should modify the `Items` class's Class Level Perrmissions to restrict these users.

**My objective**: Everyone should have access to class `Item` except a group of users. Can anyone please help

Comment: Do you mean restricting the users of Parse Dashboard to access some classes? That's currently not possible.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo No, I mean restricting the users of my application to access some classes

Comment: Got it. I think you will have to create a group called allowedUsers (not blockedUsers) and setup the CLP for only allowing allowedUsers to access the class.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo but there are like 1000 allowedUsers, do I have to manually add them all?

Comment: You can add them automatically using cloud code function or trigger.

Comment: @DaviMacêdo Thanks. I was hoping there was a way to only specify users you want to restrict.